# asp how i can redirct from folder to root folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Iam using asp.net and c#

i want to  redirect from sub folder name "pag" to root page name Default.aspx in root folder

I try  this

```
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
```

and this

```
           Response.Redirect(Server.MapPath("~/")+ "Default.aspx");
```

I got expection :

Exception Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in mscorlib.dll ("Execution thread aborted.")System.Threading.ThreadAbortException

how i cant fix it  ?
or how can redircet from folder to root ?

Comment: Could you at least glance over your question for typos before posting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path is okay, it's the way you're calling Response.Redirect that is causing the issue. Try this:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx",false);
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

You can read more about what's going on behind the scenes [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tmarq/2009/06/25/correct-use-of-system-web-httpresponse-redirect/)